# Convert GeoTIFF to Zarr Store using Xarray

Tags: geotiff-tiff, xarray

I am trying to convert my 3-band GeoTIFF to Zarr store. I am able to read in the GeoTIFF from xarray with rasterio backend.

```py
In [1]: import xarray as xr

In [2]: xtci = xr.open_dataset('tci.tif', engine='rasterio')

In [3]: xtci
Out[3]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (band: 3, x: 10980, y: 10980)
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1 2 3
  * x            (x) float64 5e+05 5e+05 5e+05 ... 6.098e+05 6.098e+05 6.098e+05
  * y            (y) float64 6e+05 6e+05 6e+05 ... 4.902e+05 4.902e+05 4.902e+05
    spatial_ref  int64 ...
Data variables:
    band_data    (band, y, x) float32 ...
```

But when I convert to Zarr store, it results in following error and terminates

```py
In [4]: xtci.to_zarr('ztci.zarr')
/home/aman/anaconda3/envs/geoenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py:2037: SerializationWarning: saving variable None with floating point data as an integer dtype without any _FillValue to use for NaNs
  return to_zarr(
Killed
```

Is it that the `dtype` of my Zarr store is `int`? If so, how to change it to `float`. If not what does the error message indicate.

Comment: Also, if anyone can add `zarr` tag that would help the community at large ( I am unable to add custom tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was arising because `zarr` was assuming the `dtype` of my variable to be integer, and because my variable contains null values, and `integer` dtype cannot handle it, it failed.

To specify the `dtype` all that needs to be done is pass the encoding specifically as shown below (see [docs](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_zarr.html#xarray-dataset-to-zarr) for more info)

```py
encoding = {i: {"dtype": "float64"} for i in xtci.data_vars}
```

and then passing that to `to_zarr` method

```py
In [10]: xtci.to_zarr('ztci_encoded.zarr', encoding=encoding)
Out[10]: <xarray.backends.zarr.ZarrStore at 0x7f4a2e6a0190>
```

Comment: I had to do something similar and also had to add  np.nan to "_FillValue"